# How to load balance 1 task per worker?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cluster-computing, load-balancing, pm2

I have a worker running in background and listening for messages via Redis. When a messages for the task start arrives, the worker starts processing it and sending a message back to Redis when the task is done.

Now, I want to optimise resources so that to be able to run an extra worker (worker per processor core) when there is already one task is being processed but a new task comes.

If I run it like this:

```
pm2 start -i max myWorker.js
```

I am seeing that 4 worker instances are started but then when I send a task, they all are being loaded and their process consumption rises up to 100% so I suspect that each of them works on the same task and as a result one task is being ran 4 times at a time which makes no sense.

What's the strategy to loadbalance the tasks between workers so that 1 tasks goes only to one worker?

Comment: Redis pub/sub is a broadcast model. When a message is published all listeners get it. What you want is a message queue. If you want only a single worker to consume it you have to do so manually using redis pub/sub, or use a different queue technology like RabbitMQ, Kafka, etc.